# Subnet a network address

Tags: subnet

From network address 10.0.0.0/10 i have to create 150 subnets with minimal number of bits borrowed.

The question is: should i borrow 8 bits or 6 bits from host part. An online subnet calculator borrowed 6 bits because 2 were already borrowed so I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

10.0.0.0/10 is the first of 4 subnets created from 10.0.0.0/8.
2 to the power of 8 = 256 subnets.
To have at least 150 subnets a Net Mask of 255.255.192.0 would have to be used.

Answer (score -2):

10.0.0.0 is a Class A Network with a Natural Mask of 255.0.0.0.  The /10 Mask is 255.192.0.0, 2 bits were borrowed to create 4 subnets. If you want 250 subnets you will want to borrow 8 bits from the natural mask to create 256 subnets.  The mask would be 255.255.0.0 .